# I can't access any database diagram

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

My databases have been working fine on my Windows Server 2016 standard. The database management system is Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Express.

Today I added a new table and content, all is fine. I tried to open the database diagram and received an error message:

[image]

And in case the image doesn't work, the message is:

> Cannot execute as the database principal because the permission "dbo" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15517)

Nothing has changed on my server - no updates, etc.

I can access all the tables. When I look at the account I log in, I can see I am a the database owner, which other posts suggest to do - but I wasn't previously so unsure as to why this would help.

This issue affects every single database I have.

The only difference is I now create a daily back up from a scheduled task with the following script

```
BACKUP DATABASE DBName TO  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\DBName .bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'DBName Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

The result of

```
SELECT ORIGINAL_LOGIN(), USER_NAME(), SUSER_SNAME();
```

shows

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting up a trace to see what query SSMS is trying to execute prior to displaying this error?

Comment: Did you deleted the owner ( the login ) of this database?

Comment: @JohnEisbrener no, I will Google how to do this. I'm not a DBA person, I'm just in charge of it

Comment: @RacerSQL, No, the log in is the main login (the account I use to login into the server)

Comment: If that login doesn't exist in sys.server_principals, then you must be obtaining access via a Windows group. Once again, try setting the authorization of the database to `sa`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because the owner of the database ( the login ) was deleted. You should remap the owner of the database, to a login that exists.

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION 
ON DATABASE::[DatabaseName]
TO [A Suitable Login];
```

Dont use `sp_changedbowner`. it's a deprecated feature.

Comment: Nothing has been deleted. No login etc. I'm the only one to access to it. I've updated to my post to explain the only change I made

Comment: But did you try to do these steps? if i'm not mistaken, [sp_changedbowner] is deprecated, so you should test with `ALTER AUTHORIZATION`. if it didnt solve the problem, just use your own login. you can see the database owner with ` right click on the database > properties > general > owner`. I'm telling you this because I had this same problem a lot of times in the past.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Nothing was necessarily deleted. It could be this database was restored from another server and the owner sid simply doesn't exist here. What account is the owner of the database? `SELECT p.name, p.type_desc
FROM sys.databases AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals AS p
ON d.owner_sid = p.sid
WHERE d.name = N'name';` - if that returns `NULL` then alter the authorization of the database to `sa`. If it doesn't return `NULL`, then maybe something is jacked with that account.

Comment: (In fact, I would remove the `sp_changeobjectowner` version. Let's not perpetuate deprecated features.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand the results pane from your query shows 2 columns, the headings are `name` and `type_desc` but there is no other information. So it doesn't return NULL

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions NULL/empty result set are functionally equivalent in this case. That means there was no match, which means the SID for the database no longer exists (or never existed on this instance). One more time, alter authorization to sa or yourself.

Comment: @AaronBertrand at the moment I log in with domain/myUser. Does this mean (using the post) I use `TO domain/myUser;` I ask because I'm not confident and if something goes wrong, I'm not sure how to revert it back

Comment: `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::dbname TO [domain\myUser];`

Comment: You can't revert it back; you won't be able to ALTER AUTH on the database to a login that doesn't exist.

Comment: Understood @AaronBertrand, When I try this I get `Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot find the principal 'LMSITES\Adminstrator', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.`

Comment: WHy don't you create a database, create a login, set it as the owner of this database, delete the login and see the error for yourself? apply what we are posting here, and see if it fixes your problem, and then, you apply in production.

Comment: @RacerSQL I'm sorry if it seems like I'm unwiling. That isn't the case, I'm just concerned I can do damage I can't resolve

Comment: No No, I know what you are felling. thats why the test database. you can mess around a lot of times until you get some confidence. this will not get you in trouble. it's a normal routine that I did a lot of times. Or better, why don't you backup this database, and restore it with something like "database_2" and trhy what I posted here.

Comment: @RacerSQL but I've applied what you've said and I have the other issue (posted in the comments)

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Then I suspect that's not the user you're actually logging in as. What does this yield? `SELECT ORIGINAL_LOGIN(), USER_NAME(), SUSER_SNAME();`

Comment: That means this login doest exists, or you have no permission. you can see the login list inside the `secutiry` folder, above the sql instance in management studio.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I updated my post to show the results. I would also like to say thank you for staying with me on this

Comment: @RacerSQL the log in exists in the security folder...